# Bootstrap: Font-Awesome does not work in subfolder?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I downloaded the [Creative](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/creative/) Bootstrap theme which has the following folder structure

```
css/
img/
js/
less/
vendor/
index.html
```

I have now created a `subfolder`, copied the `index.html` in the folder and changed the links from the `CSS` and `JS` files by adding a `../`. In particular the link for fontawesome on line 18 changed to

```
<link href="../vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

To my surprise, the font-awesome links are not working anymore:

[image]

In addition, I noticed than when I remove the dots `../` and copy the vendor folder in `subfolder` then the font-awesome icons are working.

[image]

There is no 404 error in my network tab when I open `index.html` from root or form `subfolder`. Both times it looks like this (why is Font-Awesome never listed? I pressed F5 and the `index.html` file in the root folder actually displays teh Font-Awesome icons correctly):

[image]

Why are the Font-Awesome icons not displayed correctly when the vendor folder is outside the `subfolder`?

Comment: Try using `href="/vendor/...` instead.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @Raul Firefox 54.0

Comment: I think that's it. It's a Firefox issue. For testing purposes try other browser to make sure it's not a browser thing.

Answer (score 0):

`../` is relative to the directory of the current page.  Start your href attribute with `/` to make it absolute.  Looks like it should just be `href='/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'` to me.  Using an absolute path will make it work with all pages without the need to account for the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

This happens only on local and only in Firefox. Put the files on a server and should work fine in Firefox too.

Answer (score 0):

In that html template (startbootstrap template), fontawesome icon showed if linked to two components :

- all.min.css  file in  : vendor\fontawesome-free\css
- fonts located in webfonts folder (vendor\fontawesome-free\webfonts)

if you move these files to another place, please do this :

- if your all.css file location in your css folder, please make link to
  this file.
- change link to vendor\fontawesome-free\webfonts inside all.css  file
  to your new location) or alternatively locate webfonts  folder in the
  same folder with css folder (you don't nedd change link to webfont).